# bootstrap 3 and jquery.mCustomScrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am having a issue with Bootstrap 3 modals and jquery.mCustomScrollbar. I have 6 pages all with a modal and I have implemented  jquery.mCustomScrollbar for the bootstrap modal scrollbars. The problem I am having is the  jquery.mCustomScrollbar is showing up on two of the modals and the remaining modals  jquery.mCustomScrollbar is not showing up.

Here is my bootstrap css code:

```
.modal-body {position: relative;padding: 20px;max-height: 250px;overflow:auto;}
```

and here is my js code:

```
$(".modal-body").mCustomScrollbar({advanced:{updateOnContentResize: true}});
```

Can't figure out why the `jquery.mCustomScrollbar` are 
working on two modals and not the others? Appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: Can you demonstrate your issue with an example here?  http://bootply.com/

Comment: Thanks trevor will do.